# Insert image into SQL Server database tables column

Tags: sql-server

so I created a Menu Table like this

```
create table Menu(
MenuID char(5) primary key check(menuID LIKE 'MN[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
MenuName varchar (50) not null,
MenuPrice int not null,
MenuImage varbinary(max) not null,
CategoryID char(5) references Category(CategoryID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

and I wanted to insert values into Menu but it isn't working.

```
insert into Menu values
('MN001','Mac & Cheese',60000,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Kristina\Documents\FOODS\maccheese.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1),'CA001'),
('MN002','Grilled Veggies',60000,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Kristina\Documents\FOODS\grilled.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as T2),'CA001')
```

It kept giving me: Incorrect syntax near ','. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 18.
I'm very new to this. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What is your SQL server version? SSMS version is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```
create table Menu(
MenuID char(5) primary key check(menuID LIKE 'MN[0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
MenuName varchar (50) not null,
MenuPrice int not null,
MenuImage varbinary(max) not null,
CategoryID char(5) --references Category(CategoryID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)

insert into Menu values
('MN001','Mac & Cheese',60000,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\t.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1),'CA001'),
('MN002','Grilled Veggies',60000,(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\t.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) as T2),'CA001')
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me! I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 18, does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: Add to your question the result of `select @@version`.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Comment: Cut and paste my code and run it in an SSMS query window connected to TempDb.  It will work.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
Insert into tableName (ImageColumn) 
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'image..Path..here', Single_Blob) as img
```

Paste your image path here

Comment: I also have other values I want to insert to the table, I don't think this will work?